# Load custom json file on startup

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions

I have a json file that I want to deserialize and put it in a static class on the startup of the Azure Function application, so that data of that json file can be accessed from anywhere and anytime. what would be the safest way. Can't use DI as I want to access this data from another static class.

JSON File:

```
[
  {
    "item1": "BusinessUnit",
    "item2": "BusinessUnit"
  },
  {
    "item1": "business unit",
    "item2": "BusinessUnit"
  },
  {
    "item1": "reporting entity",
    "item2": "BusinessUnit"
  }
]
```

C# Static class:

```
public static class FieldMapping
    {
        public static List<(string, string)> Mapping { get; }

        static CoaErrorFieldMapping()
        {
            Mapping = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<(string, string)>>(File.ReadAllText(@"StaticResources\Mapping.json"));
        }            
    }
```

Comment: Looks fine, what's the issue?

Comment: It will be loaded on first access, I want it to be loaded on startup

Answer (score 1):

If treating the file as custom configuration on startup :

> Custom configuration is supported with the preview package published with this release: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-extensions/releases/tag/v1.1.0-preview1
>
> Package:
> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions/1.1.0-preview1
>
> You can also find some documentation on how to use the new feature
> here:
> https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-extensions/wiki/Configuration-and-FunctionsHostBuilderContext-support

Ref : https://github.com/azure/azure-functions-dotnet-extensions/issues/17

Comment: Thanks @JayaChatterjee, what if I don't want to use IConfiguration? is it safe to load data in a static file, will it be available before my function executes and any implication of the approach when function is running in consumption plan.